# Complex setState in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a page that contains a list of orders, each with a unique orderId. Each order section on the page has two text boxes, one for trackingID and one for carrierName. I would like my input object - that is updated using the setInput function - to 'remember' all the orders that have been updated.

I have written the following code, but it overwrites the input variable if I edit a text box belonging to a different orderId.

```
const updateStatus = (e) => {
    const { id, value, name } = e.target;
  
    if (name === "trackingId") {
      setInput((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        orderId: prevState.orderId || id,
        shipData: [{ ...prevState.shipData[0], trackingId: value }],
      }));
    } else if (name === "carrierName") {
      setInput((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        orderId: prevState.orderId || id,
        shipData: [{ ...prevState.shipData[0], carrierName: value }],
      }));
    }
  
    console.log(`inputs are: ${JSON.stringify(input)}`);
  };
```

The code above produces the following object, after I edit carrierName and trackingId text boxes:

```
{"orderId":"1","shipData":[{"carrierName":"carrierOne","trackingId":"TrackingOne"}]}
```

I would like the code to, instead, create this object, if I edit a second orderId's carrierName and trackingId text boxes, i.e., I want the state to keep the previous state:

```
{"orderId":"1","shipData":[{"carrierName":"carrierOne","trackingId":"TrackingOne"}]},{"orderId":"2","shipData":[{"carrierName":"carrierTwo","trackingId":"TrackingTwo"}]}
```

For some reason, I just cannot make it work and I would really appreciate the help of someone who is cleverer than I am!

Comment: Don't know if that produces what you want already but you probably want to put curly braces around the new state's new data: `...prevState, {orderId: prevState.orderId || id, shipData: [{ ...prevState.shipData[0], trackingId: value }]},`

Comment: The second object you provided would be an array, but you are treating it in the code as an object.

Comment: did you tried useReducer hook?

https://react.dev/reference/react/useReducer

Comment: @J.Dario tried that, but no luck. Thanks for the suggestion, I think you're really close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting your input with `setInput` here in both cases - the state you are managing is just an object rather than an array like you want.

The state there is:

```
{
    orderId: number,
    shipData: Array<{ trackingValue: string, carrierName: string  }>
}
```

It seems like the output you want is to have a state like

```
Array<{
    orderId: number,
    shipData: Array<{ trackingValue: string, carrierName: string  }>
}>
```

Let me whip up a quick solution - you probably want to index here by the orderId rather than storing these in an array.

Edit:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = React.useState({});

  const updateShipDataForOrder = (orderId, shipData) => {
      setInput((prevState) => {
          // Create new ship data based on the previous data + new entry
          const newShipData = {
              ...prevState[orderId],
              ...shipData,
          };

          // Overwrite that value in our state
          const newState = {
              ...prevState,
              [orderId]: newShipData
          };

          return newState;
      })
  }

  const updateStatus = (e) => {
      const { id, value, name } = e.target;

      updateShipDataForOrder(id, { [name]: value })
  };


  // Convert back to the array you wanted
  const result = Object.entries(input).map(([orderId, shipData]) => {
      return {
          orderId,
          shipData
      }
  })

  return (
      <div>
        <div>
            <h1>Order one</h1>
            Tracking ID: <input id="1" name="trackingId" onChange={updateStatus} />
            Carrier Name: <input id="1" name="carrierName" onChange={updateStatus} />
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>Order two</h1>
            Status: <input id="2" name="trackingId" onChange={updateStatus} />
            Carrier Name: <input id="2" name="carrierName" onChange={updateStatus} />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>result: {JSON.stringify(result, null, '\t')}</div>
      </div>
  )
}

const root = document.getElementById('root')

ReactDOM.render(<App />, root)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me out! Unfortunately, this also just overwrites the input variable with the new object, after I add text to the carrierName or trackingId fields of the second orderId section

Comment: I've edited with a quick demo that you might be able to adapt for your usecase.